# How to evaluate $\lim_{b \to \infty} \left[\frac{b^{t-1}}{e^b}\right]$?

Tags: limits

I encountered this limit when I studied the the gamma function. This limit arises when integrating the gamma function by parts. The author evaluates it as follows:

1. $\lim\limits_{b \to \infty} \left[\dfrac{b^{t-1}}{e^b}\right] =-\lim\limits_{b \to \infty} \left\{\dfrac{\text{exp}[(t-1) \ln b]}{\text{exp}(b)}\right\}$
2. $\lim\limits_{b \to \infty} \left[\dfrac{b^{t-1}}{e^b}\right] =-\lim\limits_{b \to \infty}\{\text{exp}[(t-1) \ln b-b]\}$
3. $\lim\limits_{b \to \infty} \left[\dfrac{b^{t-1}}{e^b}\right] =-\lim\limits_{b \to \infty} \left\{\text{exp}\left[(t-1)b\left(\dfrac{ \ln b}{b}-1\right)\right]\right\}$

And finally, by l’Hôpital's rule:
$$\dfrac{ \ln b}{b} = 0$$
then $$\lim\limits_{b \to \infty} e^{(t-1)b(0-1)} = \lim\limits_{b \to \infty} e^{-\infty}=0.$$

I can not make sense of the manipulation between step 2 and 3. Can someone offer an explanation? Thanks in advance.

Source: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/142

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{e^{(t-1)\log b}}{e^b}=e^{(t-1)\log b-b}$$

and now just factor out $\;b\;$ in the exponent:

$$(t-1)\log b-b=b\left((t-1)\frac{\log b}b-1\right)$$

...and there's a mistake, either in your writing or in the book, as the factor $\;(t-1)\;$ does **not** multiply the whole thing, only $\;\log b\;$ ...

Comment: It's been bugging me for 2 hours. Well it does look like they made a mistake. And thank you very much.